# Seeking open source or LGPL replacement for var_dump()

Tags: php

Before I code my own ... I have tried all the code in the PHP manual and not of it is very good. I have Gogoled for hours, but tend to find only GPL code, which can't be included in a commercial product (I'm just a guy trying to make a few bucks on the side, not working for a mega-corporation which could develop or buy code).

Things like [Krumo](http://krumo.kaloyan.info/) look very good, but are actually too sophisticated for me. For instance, I don't want to click to expand, since I want to use the code in my error page and have the user copy/paste it into an email or print it out & fax it.

What I want is table dump, recursed, preferably with variable type as well as value and a count of array members (maybe string lengths too). Something static, simple and straightforward, which will mostly be used to dump $_SESSION on the error page (oh, and a nicely formatted stack trace would be nice too ;-)

---

Update: Please, standalone code only; nothing that is part of a framework. Thanks.

Comment: All these things (`$_SESSION`, `$GLOBALS`, `$_SERVER`, `debug_backtrace()`, etc) are generally arrays, which you can easily `print_r()` or `foreach` over.  It really doesn't take a specialized library to output or capture this information.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, depends. Storing `debug_backtrace()` in a parsable way may be PITA, if you want to store all function arguments which may be quite complex objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for Zend.

```
Zend_Debug::dump($data);
```

**neatly** prints out your data including arrays.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.debug.dumping.html

Regarding the commercial usage, **you can**.

Check the last point in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773/zend-php-framework/257261#257261

Regarding the usage of this method as a standalone without the entire Zend Framework, **you can**.

Check the second point here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework#Features

Comment: +1 but ... 1) if I don't use the Zend framework, can I use it standalone? and, 2) can I use commercially without having to pay for it

Comment: I awarded you the answer but, typically, I am going to roll my own. Thanks for the help, though

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be any good for you -> http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Debug

Comment: +1 but it's difficult to tell. At first glance I didn't see any example output

Comment: Yeah, kohanas docs are bit short on info (but they are being steadily improved). Nevertheless kohana is a great framework with great helpers (debug is one of those)

Comment: +1 again, but I am looking for a stand-alone solution, rather than a framework

Comment: you can use "Debug" class as standalone. It's not tied to framework :)